# Image to byte[] hangs indefinitely

Tags: c#, arrays, image, memorystream

```
var originalImageBytes = originalFile.FileBytes();

// Convert bytes to image
Image originalImage;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(originalImageBytes))
{
    originalImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
}

// Convert back to byte array
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    originalImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Returning `originalImageBytes` at any point works fine, however the program hangs indefinitely on the final `return ms.ToArray()` line.

Why is `ms.ToArray()` causing a hang?

Answer (score 3):

It might be related to some strange behavior from `Image` using a `Stream`. You [have to keep open the stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) until you are done with the image, since `Image` can lazy-load the content at will.

It is possible that the `Save` in fact triggers reading the (then) closed and disposed `MemoryStream`. Try to see what happens if you don't close the stream.

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  If I change the first block to `Bitmap originalImage;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(originalImageBytes))
            {
                originalImage = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));
            }` it works fine.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, don't do the code above!  I think .net garbage collector messes with it and you get strange behaviour even when creating a Bitmap object from the Image object.  Keeping the original image memory stream open for the entire method is the only thing that works properly.

Comment: That because the image heavily depends on handles to Windows. Closing the memory stream clears the memory block it references.